# How to decay all variadic template parameters?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Is there a way to decay all types in variable template argument pack into their value types?

For example:

```
template < typename... T >
void foo( T... ts )    // I do not want to have references here
{
}
template < typename... T >
void bar( T&&... ts )
{
    foo( ts );
}
```

So, what I would like to do is something like [std::decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), but on whole variadic template pack. How to do that?

If I call those functions like this:

```
struct A{
};
A a;
bar( 3, a, 5.5f );
```

then I want all to be copied and passed by value to the function `foo`.

PS: My compiler is gcc 6.2.0 and supports up to c++17

Comment: Did `std:decay_t<T>... ts` not work? I'm assuming you've tried it.

Comment: I'm confused. `foo(ts...);` already copies the arguments.

Comment: @T.C. Why not answer then? Is `void foo( T... ts )` enough to be sure that all types in the packs copy arguments? Is there a case when one of types get a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template argument deduction for `template < typename... T > void foo( T... ts );` will always deduce a "decayed" type. (Indeed, the original goal of `decay` is to perform the type transformations you get when passing something by value.)

Of course, the user can still explicitly write `foo<int&>(...)`. If you care about such things (Murphy/Machiavelli/etc.), a `static_assert` should suffice:

```
static_assert((std::is_same_v<T, std::decay_t<T>> && ...), "Hello, Machiavelli!");
```

Comment: Sounds good, but where do I put that static assert? And how exactly to write it for variadic pack?

Comment: @BЈовић In `foo`'s body. And the form I wrote is variadic.

Comment: When you say "decayed" type, does that include array to pointer conversion?

Comment: Having done a bit of poking around on godbolt, it appears it does.

Comment: I am still learning new features, and variadic templates must be the one of crazier things. BTW `std::is_same_v` is not in my version of c++17, so I used `std::is_same`.